# Problema al copiar o mover archivos a una subcarpeta dentro de la carpeta de origen (src)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un script que copia archivos de una carpeta a otra recursivamente dependiendo de las extensiones y funciona bien hasta que Dst está en Src. Me explico:

Si envío, por ejemplo, archivos .txt a una subcarpeta que está en Src, a la segunda vuelta del ciclo for el código analizara Dst y como anteriormente ya había pasado archivos, creara dentro de Dst otra carpeta con el mismo nombre y copiara nuevamente los archivos. En otras palabras, se clona. ¿hay alguna forma de evitar que esto ocurra? He probado con un continue, y funciona hasta que copio o muevo archivos a una subcarpeta de un nivel mas bajo.

Como pueden ver en la siguiente imagen la carpeta "folder3" se copio a si misma y dentro puso los archivos y es algo realmente molesto ya que vuelve todo una mescolanza cuando hay mas carpetas y archivos.

[image: Imagen 1]

Asi es como luce una supuesta ruta de origen:

```
My documents
--- file.txt
--- folder (subfolder)
    --- file2.txt
--- Text_files (subfolder) Dst
```

Así es como funciona actualmente si quiero que el script copie desde Src (My Documents) sólo los archivos .txt a Dst (Text_Files) manteniendo recursivamente la jerarquía de carpetas:

```
My documents
--- file.txt
--- folder (subfolder)
    --- file2.txt
--- Text_files (subfolder) Dst
    ---file.txt
    ---Text_files (Subfolder) <- Noten como la carpeta 'Text_files' se copia a si misma
       --- folder (subfolder)
           --- file2.txt
       ---file.txt
       --- folder (subfolder)
           --- file2.txt
```

Como debería ser:

```
My documents (Src)
---file.txt
--- Text_files (Subfolder) Dst
      ---file.txt
--- folder (subfolder)
    --- file2.txt
```

Mi codigo:

```
import os
import shutil


# Copia archivos filtrándolos por extensiones de una carpeta a otra manteniendo la estructura de carpetas.
def copywf1(Src, Dst, extensions):

    try:
        item_list = os.listdir(Src)
        for item in item_list:
            source_fn = os.path.join(Src, item)

            if os.path.isdir(source_fn):
                copywf1(source_fn, os.path.join(Dst, item), extensions)

            elif os.path.splitext(item)[1] in extensions:

                if not os.path.exists(Dst):
                    os.makedirs(Dst)

                shutil.copyfile(source_fn, os.path.join(Dst, item))

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        pass

copywf1(r"SRC", r"DST", [".txt"])
```

Comment: Probé tu código, sin embargo use `shutil.copyfile` en lugar de `winshell` dado que no tengo windows. y tu código parece funcionar bien. Lo hace como lo esperado. Podrías revisar bien la librería, y quizá alguno de los parámetros opcionales que le pasas es lo que lo ocasione, si no intenta con otra librería.

Comment: Buenas! gracias pro tu tiempo en responderme. Has probado exactamente lo que menciono en mi pregunta ? porque el problema no tiene que ver con el metodo de copiado, sino con el código que hay antes. Hay carpetas que se copian a si mismas y eso es un problema que de verdad no se como abordar. Crea una carpeta de origen y dentro, crea  subcarpeta y luego otra dentro de la anterior. A esta ultima subcarpeta es donde enviaras los archivos. Notaras enseguida el problema al cual me refiero.

Comment: Sí, probé tu código tal cual, lo copié en un archivo, cree la misma estructura que das en el ejemplo y funciona tal cual lo esperas, no crea dos `text_files`, nuevamente menciono lo único quw cambie fue `shutil.copyfile` ya que no tengo windows. Deberías probar así ya que al menos al probarlo yo, funciono bien tu código

Comment: Ya intente con shutil pero sigue pasándome lo mismo, dejo estas 3 imágenes como ejemplo.                                                                                                                                                                                                                        https://i.gyazo.com/a07155b01775eb01af80b0cbeab4afa9.png                                https://i.gyazo.com/ac540eb8bb9719d87e515bf02c112e5a.png                                    https://i.gyazo.com/440182a371f7320984a4b3359018a02d.png

Comment: folder2 y folder3(DST) se copian dos veces. Cuando solo debería de haber archivos en Python/folder1(SRC)/folder2/folder3(DST) he pensado en hacer que los archivos se copien a una carpeta temporal y luego los mueva a la carpeta DST pero tomaría el doble de tiempo hacer la transferencia y debería de haber el doble de espacio en el disco duro.

Comment: En todo caso pon otro ejemplo con más iteraciones, Pon la estructuras de un ejemplo que arroje ese error. ya que como menciona @GmrYael, el ejemplo que pusiste funciona sin problemas y no le vemos nada malo.

Comment: Me di cuenta de que la condicional if source_fn == Dst: no dejaba que se mostrara el problema tal como les comento. He modificado el codigo de mi pregunta en base al codigo de @GmrYael y ahora si lo prueban notaran que sucede lo que les digo.

Comment: pero si con el `if source_fn == Dst` funciona, por qué no dejarlo así? Si no funciona con esa cnondición muestra que es lo que no funciona de esa parte.

Comment: Es que es un paño de agua tibia. Con esa condicional todo funciona bien mientras Dst sea solo una subcarpeta, pero si es una sub-subcarpeta entonces sucede lo que comento. El código copia de nuevo los archivos recién copiados a DST creando por el camino otra vez esta carpeta. Lo que me extraña es que no se quede en un bucle infinito, eso seria peor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese if solo funcionaba a un nivel porque verificaba que las carpetas sean iguales.

es decir en la siguiente estructura

```
My documents (Src)
---file.txt
--- Text_files (Subfolder) Dst
      ---file.txt
--- folder (subfolder)
    --- file2.txt
```

Creaba el subfolder `Dst` quedando así

```
My documents (Src)
    ---file.txt
    --- Text_files (Subfolder) Dst
          ---file.txt
    --- folder (subfolder)
        --- file2.txt
    --- Dst (Dst)
```

Cuando llegaba al subfolder, el origen era `Src/Dst` y el destino era `Src/Dst`, por lo cual al llegar al if entonces lo detenía

El problema era si el destino era que si estaba en un subnivel, como no eran iguales se creaba, pero dentro de la carpeta, como ya se igualaban, se detenía, por eso no era infinito el ciclo y por eso entre a más subniveles lo pongas lo anidaba más veces.

Esta podría ser una solución

```
import os
import shutil


def copywf1(Src, Dst, extensions):

    try:

        for item in os.listdir(Src):
            source_fn = os.path.join(Src, item)
            print(source_fn, Dst)

            if os.path.isdir(source_fn):
                split_dst = os.path.normpath(Dst).split(os.sep)
                if not all([path in split_dst for  path in os.path.normpath(source_fn).split(os.sep)]):
                    copywf1(source_fn, os.path.join(Dst, item), extensions)

            elif os.path.splitext(item)[1] in extensions:

                if not os.path.exists(Dst):
                    os.makedirs(Dst)

                shutil.copyfile(source_fn, os.path.join(Dst, item))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    copywf1(r"docs", r"docs/dst/text_files", ".txt")
```

Comment: Gracias, funciono, pero no crea todas las subcarpetas en Dst. Solo copia las subcarpetas de primer nivel y no sigue mas. Me parece extraño ya que  if not os.path.exists(Dst): deberia ser True y deberia crearla.

Comment: Probé el código pero no vi hasta cuantas subcarpetas funcionaba. Con esta nueva aproximación puedes buscarle un rato y si vuelves a tener dudas puedes volver.

Comment: Me pondré a ello y comentare mis resultados en un rato. Ya intente colocar  if not os.path.exists(Dst): en varios lugares distintos pero no funciona..

Answer (score 1):

Probé tu codigo al igual que el usuario  @Sr1871 con la unica variante que utlizamos el metodo `copyfile` de la libreria `shutil`

```
import os
import shutil


# Copia archivos filtrándolos por extensiones de una carpeta a otra manteniendo la estructura de carpetas.
def copywf1(Src, Dst, extensions):

    try:
        item_list = os.listdir(Src)
        for item in item_list:
            source_fn = os.path.join(Src, item)

            if source_fn == Dst:
                continue

            elif source_fn != Dst:

                if os.path.isdir(source_fn):
                    copywf1(source_fn, os.path.join(Dst, item), extensions)

                elif os.path.splitext(item)[1] in extensions:

                    if not os.path.exists(Dst):
                        os.makedirs(Dst)

                    shutil.copyfile(source_fn, os.path.join(Dst, item))

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        pass


source = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Source")
destiny = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Source/Destiny")
copywf1(source, destiny, [".txt"])
```

y el resultado fue el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No veo nada mal en tu codigo.

Comment: Hola, GmYael. En la respuesta que le di a Sr1871 se puede ver mas claramente lo que me esta sucediendo. Hay carpetas que se copian a si misma cuando DST es una sub-sub carpeta de Src. En tu caso no sucedio lo que me pasa a mi porque source_fn == Dst se cumple, pero si lo intentas con otra sub carpeta veras como si te pasa. Por otro lado, los archivos deben de estar directamente en la carpeta Source, no en una subcarpeta.

Comment: Supón que tengo unas películas cada una en carpetas diferentes en mi carpeta de descargas que quiero pasar a una carpeta llamada "Películas" que esta junto a las demás. Por lo que comento, esto hará que se clonen carpetas y archivos y la carpeta "Películas" quedara desordenada y me tocara a mi ordenar todo. Me toca, entonces, pasar las películas a una carpeta que no este en la carpeta de descargas y después moverlas a DST pero esto es ineficiente.

Comment: Dentro de la carpeta "Destiny" (Src)  crea otra carpeta y dentro de esta, crea otra y envía ahí los archivos. Notaras a lo que me refiero.